# The Kaplan-Meier weighted generalized M-estimation

Tags: regression, linear-model, robust, kaplan-meier

Consider linear regression model:
\begin{equation*}
    y_i  = x_i^T \beta + \sigma \epsilon,
\end{equation*}
where $y_i = \min(T_i,C_i)$ (failure time and censoring time).
Can someone explain me the intuition behind the kaplan meier weighted generalized M-estimation? The solution $(\beta,\sigma)$ that minimizes:
\begin{equation*}
        Q_n(\theta)=\displaystyle \sum_i W_{ni}\left\{\rho 
\left[\dfrac{\omega_i(y_i - x_i^T \beta)}{\sigma}\right] + \log \sigma\right\},
\end{equation*}
where $\rho$ is some 'robust' function, $\omega_i = \left\{ 1 + (x_i - M_n)^TV_n^{-1}(x_i-M_n)/d\right\}^{-1/2}$ with $M_n,V_n$ robust measures of location and scale. Finally, the $W_{ni}$ are the jumps of the kaplan meier distribution of the failure time $T$.

Approach: The $\rho$-function is to bound the influence of vertical outliers. The $w_i$ to bound the influence of leverage points. But why is the $\log \sigma $-term?